# Clang-format enforce using typename instead of class

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there a way to have clang-format turn this:

```
template<class T>
class Foo;
```

Into this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo;
```

Comment: Hopefully there isn't, both are legal. Why would you enforce this (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @lorro: style consistency I would say.

Comment: @lorro seems a reasonable thing to do for me, the idea of clang-format is to enable consistent code formatting. Whilst `class` vs `typename` isn't really a formatting issue it could still be desirable to use a consistent convention within a codebase

Comment: For me, it'd make sense e.g. to use `typename` when both classes and base types can appear (e.g. `MyClass` and `int`), whereas `class` to denote that it is an actual class. Maybe that's just me...

Comment: @lorro whether using `class` or `typename` is rather matter of taste, but code consistency has nothing to do with legality guide. It helps to use unified approach across a team/project which in turn makes entire codebase look consistent and even saves development time from everyone rewriting different parts of code in accordance with their personal preferences.

Comment: @lorro yes, it is about consistency across the code base.